# C++ - Class does not name a type

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, debian, ubuntu-13.10

I am instructed to code a Blackjack project for my college CMSC class. I have made all required source files but there is an error that I cannot figure out. I am using the terminal with a Makefile to compile my program.

When I compile my program I get this error in the terminal along with other warnings (I am not concerned about the warnings).

```
In file included from Blackjack.h:19:0,
                 from Proj2.cpp:12:

Player.h:17:3: error: ‘Hand’ does not name a type
   Hand hand;
   ^

In file included from Blackjack.h:19:0,
                 from Blackjack.cpp:1:

Player.h:17:3: error: ‘Hand’ does not name a type
   Hand hand;
```

Here is my source code in a Github repository.

https://github.com/Terrablezach/Blackjack

Can anyone tell me why the class 'Hand' does not name a type? I have included it in my header files where it needs to be included and I don't understand why it does not recognize it as a class.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: what files are you permitted to edit/modify? I note in one of your other comments you state you are not permitted to edit the blackjack.h file, any more you cannot modify? (that way I know how best to formulate my answer)

Comment: [Here](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/courses/undergraduate/202/spring14/projects/project2/) is the link to my project description. The classes that they provide us (They are a bit down on the page as links) are not permitted to be modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the project brief you can change code, correct errors and include orders, however it states you cannot change the function declarations (this will be to limit the possible number of variations in code functionality I would suspect).

The function declaration is simply this line: `Player(char *newName, int newFunds)`

Looking at your code you are potentially going to run into problems with circular inclusion in your headers.

What you could do is wrap each header in a small piece of logic to prevent the same file from being included multiple times, for example add the lines

```
#pragma once
//  the #pragma effectively does the same as the #ifndef/#define lines, 
//  its the equivalent of belt and braces if you use both
#ifndef HAND_H
#define HAND_H
//normal hand.h code in here
#endif
```

that way no matter how many times you call on the hand.h file you cannot end up with a multiply defined/included header.  As a matter of rote I do that with all my header files whilst doing rapid development.

In regards specifically to the error `Player.h:17:3: error: ‘Hand’ does not name a type
   Hand hand;`  I suspect the previous comment in regards to the include order is correct, however I have no linux environment to hand, but will get back to you later tonight/tomorrow:)

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer, you don't know how long it has been bugging me. I had no idea you could do this in C++, I am a bit new to the language. One thing however, when you say #def it should actually be #define (At least that is how it looks in the other .h files).

Comment: absolutely correct:) sorry was thinking too slow and typing too fast.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't included `Hand.h` in `Player.h`, so the definition of `Hand` is not available there.

Comment: Why the downvote? Look at the code, this is clearly the case. `Player.h` includes `Blackjack.h` which includes `Player.h` before `Hand.h` so that the definition is not available.

Comment: I see your point, I am not allowed to update the 'Blackjack.h' header file in any way. Is there any way I could rewrite my code so that this can work? (I know there is because students have already done the projects). Please let me know if you are able to figure it out.

Comment: You could forward-declare the Hand class in `Player.h` instead of including `Blackjack.h`, and use it as a pointer member in Player. In `Player.cpp`, you could then include `Blackjack.h` or `Hand.h` to be able to call functions of `Hand`.

Comment: I'm sorry for asking again, but could you possibly illustrate this in code? I am relatively new to C++ and my class has not covered a lot since we are on spring break.

Answer (score 1):

The order of the #include declarations is incorrect.

Player class is dependant upon the declaration of Hand class. So in Blackjack.h the #include for Hand.h must go **before** the #include for Player.h

```
#ifndef BLACKJACK_H
#define BLACKJACK_H

#include <vector>
#include "Hand.h"    // must be before Player.h include
#include "Player.h"
```

Alternatively, a forward declaration can be used in Player.h.

```
class Hand;  // forward declaration of class Hand

class Player {
 public:
  Player();
  Player(char *newName, int newFunds);
  ...
  ...
```

Comment: I know this may be an easy way of fixing this problem, but sadly I am not allowed to edit the 'Blackjack.h' header file in any way due to the requirements of my CMSC professor. Is there any other option to fix this error?

Comment: Yes, use a forward declaration of `Hand` - see edited answer.